# bootstrapshuffle frontend add to django 3.0 project

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I am building my CSS/JS/html basic site on https://bootstrapshuffle.com/ that I have exported and try to add to my Django 3.0 project.

**Requirements**

- Django 3.0
- python 3.7
- macOS 10.12

**Terminal Error Messages**

(after you start solving them it will show more error messages until you put everything to the right place)

```
Not Found: /js/jquery/jquery.min.js
[03/Mar/2020 14:31:28] "GET /js/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2568
Not Found: /placeholder/icons/check.svg
[03/Mar/2020 14:31:28] "GET /placeholder/icons/check.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 2580
Not Found: /js/popper/popper.min.js
Not Found: /js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js
[03/Mar/2020 14:31:28] "GET /js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2586
Not Found: /css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
[03/Mar/2020 14:31:28] "GET /css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2592
[03/Mar/2020 14:31:28] "GET /js/popper/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2568
Not Found: /js/popper/popper.min.js
[03/Mar/2020 14:31:28] "GET /js/popper/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2568
Not Found: /js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js
[03/Mar/2020 14:31:28] "GET /js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2586
```

Comment: even if there is a CSS file involved, this is not a CSS issue so no need the CSS tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Django Project folder structure**

> MyDjangoProjectName
>
> > MainProjectAppFolder
> >
> > > static

When I have putted anywhere other than the `static` folder the folders and reconnected them they did not worked. So I could only make it work by putting them to `static` folder.

added files/folders inside **static**

- public
- src
- package.json

**settings.py**

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'MainProjectFolder/static/')]`

I have my HTML files in different parts of the projects under templates ex.: `MyDjangoProjectName/AAAappfolder/templates/AAAappfolder/home.html` I have basically copied and pasted the original HTML code here to my django HTML file. Than corrected each element as follows ex.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/public/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<img class="mr-2 mt-2" src="static/public/placeholder/icons/check.svg" alt="">
<script src="static/public/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/public/js/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/public/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```